# Ubuntu Touch on Galaxy nexus - Device not found on server

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to install Ubuntu Touch on my Galaxy Nexus (Tuna device) and when I want to flash the device, terminal returns : 
Device tuna not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu

I tried others servers and I got the same error.

Can you help me or guide me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Back in January 2014, support for the Galaxy Nexus was dropped because the overhead of maintaining it for Ubuntu touch was too high. ([Source](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg05889.html))